# Quantikz breaks spacing in tikz matrices/tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikz-matrix

For now, If I just create a simple diagram with all `inner sep` and `outer sep` set to 0, I still have no spacing:

[image]

Now, if I also load quantikz, the spacing is bad (quantikz also breaks the baseline, but this is easy to fix):

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
%% Really Breaks spacing:
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
% Even without quantikz, the spacing is not null. With quantikz, it gets even worse.
Hello \fbox{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,baseline={([yshift=-axis_height]current bounding box.center)},]|[draw,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]|A\end{tikzcd}}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the problem. The problem is that `quantikz` patches a `tikzcd` function (and another one):

```
\patchcmd\tikzcd@{\tikzpicture}{\def\toslice{0}\def\vert{0}
 \begin{tikzpicture}}{}{}
```

and it forgets to put a `%`, i.e. it should be:

```
\patchcmd\tikzcd@{\tikzpicture}{\def\toslice{0}\def\vert{0}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}}{}{}
```

To temporarily use the original function I did that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\makeatletter
\let\tikzcd@@original\tikzcd@%
\let\endtikzcd@original\endtikzcd%
\makeatother
%% Really Breaks spacing:
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
% Even without quantikz, the spacing is not null. With quantikz, it gets even worse.
{
  \makeatletter
  \let\tikzcd@\tikzcd@@original
  \let\endtikzcd\endtikzcd@original
  \makeatother
  Hello \fbox{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,baseline={([yshift=-axis_height]current bounding box.center)},]|[draw,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]|A\end{tikzcd}}.
}

\end{document}
```

Concerning the baseline, I think it comes from the line

```
/tikz/baseline={([yshift=-\MathAxis]\noexpand\tikzcdmatrixname-\wholepart-1.base)}
```

and

```
/tikz/baseline={([yshift=-\MathAxis]$(\noexpand\tikzcdmatrixname-\wholepart-1.base)!\fractionalpart!(\noexpand\tikzcdmatrixname-\neighbour-1.base)$)}
```